# Is it possible to integrate $\int_{0} ^{x1} e^{h-k\sqrt{x^2+bx+c}}dx$ analytically?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to model atmosphere scattering in realtime, and solving this equation numerically takes quite a long time on GPU. I was trying to find an analytic solution, but both Maxima and my limited knowledge failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+e%5E%28h-ksqrt%28ax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%29%29+dx), no there is no analytic way.